# Formulation of axiom of induction?

Tags: logic, higher-order-logic

Tthe axiom of induction has the following second order formulation:

$$\forall \phi :\left(\phi(0)\wedge \forall n\in \mathbb{N} :\left( \phi(n)\Rightarrow \phi(n+1)\right)\right)\Rightarrow \forall n\in \mathbb{N}: \phi(n)$$

Here $\phi(n)$ is a formula which is a result of (properly) replacing one of the free variables in $\phi$ with $n$ , but obviously in the above axiom the same variable was replaced with $0,n$ and $n+1$.

The above could better be formulated as 
$$\forall \phi(x) :\left(\phi[x/0]\wedge \forall n\in \mathbb{N} :\left( \phi[x/n]\Rightarrow \phi[x/n+1]\right)\right)\Rightarrow \forall n\in \mathbb{N}: \phi[x/n]$$

where the implicit **replace same variable** condition was made explicit. But there is still a meta-theoretical $\phi(x)$ which means $x$ is a free variable in $\phi$ and $\phi[x/y]$ which is the formula that is a result of proper replacement of $x$ in $\phi$ with $y$. (So $x$ is not an object but a label.)

***Question***:
can this axiom be formulated without meta-logical side-notes? (because as far as I know ***x* being a free variable in $\phi$** is not a valid sentence in any formal logic)?

Note: I know about the other formulation with sets but still not satisfactory as $x\in \{y:\phi\}$ is defined as $\phi[y/x]$.

Comment: I might oversee something, but: using the formulation with sets seems to me a pure object-language version as long as $\in$ is part of the language. So, I would say I need a refinement of the question: what is the object-language you want to consider?

Comment: well, in ZFC if $x\in \{y\in z:\phi\}$ I think it is safe to conclude that $x\in z \wedge \phi[y/x]$ but since $\phi[y/x]$ is not part of the language what is the logical equivalent that is part of the language?

Comment: Usually the language of second-order arithmetic is $\mathcal L = \{ 0, s, +, \cdot, <, \in\}$. Hence by merely expressing natural deduction using $\in$ it is purely object-language. Although the meaning *might be* expressed using meta-language.

Comment: If $x$ is not a free variable of $\phi$ then $\phi[x/n]$ is the same as $\phi$, which can be proved by the inductive definition of substitution. So it is not necessary to state that $x$ is a free variable of $\phi$.

Comment: Have you seen how induction is formulated in PRA?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_arithmetic

Comment: @aphorisme: "oversee" $\ne$ "overlook" =)

Comment: @user21820 ha. Old false friend.  ; ).

Answer (score 3):

#### Language in Question

I think the question cannot be answered as stated since there is a crucial part of information missing: what is the object-language in question? Since you want to formalize the induction axiom in this object-language.

Insofar, I assume the following (usual) object-language since the theory you're interested in is probably second-order arithmetic:

$$ \mathcal L = \{0, s, +, \cdot, <, \in\}$$

This means: all those symbols can be used to build up formulas within the object-language.

#### Formulating Induction

Given $\mathcal L$ we can formulate:

$$\forall X. (0 \in X \wedge (\forall n . n \in X \to s(n) \in X)) \to \forall n . n \in X$$

This is a statement merely in the object-language.

Its meaning is what defines natural induction if taken to account that using the usual comprehension principle we can capture every (almost; if not paradoxical) property as membership of a specific set. But this fact is nothing we have to make to write down the sentence above.

If the sentence captures what we understand under natural induction though is a philosophical question IMO.