# Logical equivalent of $\phi[x/y]$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, higher-order-logic

In ZFC if $x\in \{y\in z:\phi\}$ I think it is safe to conclude that $x\in z \wedge \phi[y/x]$ but since $\phi[y/x]$ is not part of the language what is the logical equivalent that is part of the language?

In the same manner $(\forall x:\phi) \Rightarrow \phi[x/y]$ but again $\phi[x/y]$ is not part of the language, could it be extended to include it? (I doubt since in $\phi[x/y]$ "x" is a label and is directly bound to the physical representation of $\phi$)?

Comment: Why "$ϕ[y/x]$ is not part of the languigae" ? If so, you cannot "write"  $x ∈ \{ y∈z : ϕ \}$.

Comment: $ϕ[y/x]$ simply is the formula $ϕ$ with the variable $x$ replaced by $y$. This "operation" is defined for every formula of the language.

Comment: I am well aware what it means, my "problem" is with the "predicate" **x being a variable in $\phi$**  because how could an object *be a variable*

Comment: No; they are *expressions*, i.e. syntactical objects. $x$ is a *variable* of the language; $x \in y$ is a *formula* of the language. The expression $\{ y : ϕ \}$ produce from a formula $ϕ$ a *term* of the language, i.e. a "name". $ϕ[y/x]$ is nothing more than the result of replacing the var $y$ in place of $x$ into the formula $ϕ$. If $ϕ$ is e.g. $x \in \emptyset$, then  $ϕ[y/x]$ is $y \in \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, another try, after this one: [Formulation of axiom of induction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896878/formulation-of-axiom-of-induction)

#### Reframing the problem

I'm still thinking you got something confused about meta-statements and statements in the object-language. Since it is the same for me from time to time I might be just biased. But I hope to enable you to clarify the question for yourself at least.

The statement

$$\text{In ZFC if }x \in \{ y \in z : \phi \}\text{, then }x \in z \wedge \phi[y/x]$$

is clearly a meta-statement. **Even if you formalize** $\phi[y/x]$ within the object-language it is **still a meta statement** since you're talking about an **arbitrary** $\phi$!

So, say $\phi[y/x]$ was a sentence in the object-language *for every* $\phi$. Then the statement

$$x\in\{y\in z : \phi \} \to x \in z \wedge \phi[y/x]$$

would be still a meta statement, because in fact it says:

$$\text{for all formula }\phi\text{ it holds that } x\in\{y\in z : \phi \} \to x \in z \wedge \phi[y/x].$$

The part which uses mathematical symbols is still meta statement if you look twice, since it is a scheme.

#### Comments

If you, though, take a certain instance, i.e. a specific formula for that $\phi$ you get a specific formula $\phi[y/x]$ and hence you're able to proof it using no meta mumbo jumbo but at the cost of the generality.

You might have come across exercises which tell you to prove $\phi \vee \neg \phi$ or such. In fact, even if you use a calculus, you're still proving it encapsulated within meta: for every $\phi$ show that $\phi \vee \neg\phi$. Now, what you are doing is meta generialization: Let $\phi$ be any formula, then ...

Another way you might consider is **encoding "x is free in $\phi$"** into the language of ZFC. Something like Gödel numbers for formulae; such that you can talk about an arbitrary formula *within* the object language by quantifying over all Gödel numbers which represent a valid formula. I've no clue if this is possible though. But my intuition tells me that this is not what you're looking for. I might be wrong though.

Comment: what i am ultimately thinking is that $\phi[x/y]$ is not a valid sentence (but unfortunately $\forall x:\psi$ feels the same)